# Concerned about race conditions while accessing SQLite3 database connection that's accessed in thread invoked by Pynput listener inside a QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, qthread, pyside2

I'm writing a Windows application with Pyside2. Due to the nature of how I'm using multithreading, I'm having to interact with the same Sqlite3 database in multiple threads. I've created a <100 line [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that nearly identically replicates the problem.

**The problem:** I'm currently using the [pynput module](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) to monitor key activity in the background once the PushButton has been pressed, while the Qt GUI is out of focus for a hotkey combination of "j" + "k". Once the hot key combination is pressed, a screenshot is taken, the image is processed via OCR and saved to a database along with the OCR text. The image path is sent through a a series of connected signals to the main GUI thread. The key monitoring happens in another `QThread` to prevent the key monitoring and image processing from affecting the main Qt event loop from running. Once the QThread starts and emits it's start signal I call the `monitor_for_hot_key_combo` function in the key_monitor instance which instantiates `listener`as a `threading.Thread`, which is assigned key_monitor member functions `on_release` and `on_press` as callbacks, which are called every time a key is pressed.

This is where the problem lies. Those callbacks interact with the `imageprocessing_obj` instance of the `image_process`class in a different thread than the class was instantiated in. Therefore, when `image_process` member functions are interacted with that use the SQlite database, they do so in a separate thread than the database connection was created in. [Now, SQLite "can be safely used by multiple threads](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) provided that **no single database connection is used simultaneously** in two or more threads". To allow this you
have to set the `check_same_thread` argument for `sqlite3.connect()` to False. However, Id rather avoid this mulithreaded access of the database if possible to prevent undefined behavior.

**The Possible solution:** I've been wondering if the two threads, both `threading.Thread` and `QThread` aren't necessary and it can all be done within the Pynput thread. However, I can't seem to figure out how to just use the Pynput thread while still being able to send signals back to the main Qt event loop.

**qtui.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import *
import HotKeyMonitor

class Ui_Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker = None

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pressbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pressbutton.setObjectName("PushButton")
        self.pressbutton.clicked.connect(self.RunKeyMonitor)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pressbutton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Press me", None, -1))

    def RunKeyMonitor(self):
        self.Thread_obj = QThread()
        self.HotKeyMonitor_Obj = HotKeyMonitor.key_monitor()
        self.HotKeyMonitor_Obj.moveToThread(self.Thread_obj)
        self.HotKeyMonitor_Obj.image_processed_km.connect(self.print_OCR_result)
        self.Thread_obj.started.connect(self.HotKeyMonitor_Obj.monitor_for_hotkey_combo)
        self.Thread_obj.start()

    def print_OCR_result(self, x):
        print("Slot being called to print image path string")
        print(x)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**HotKeyMonitor.py**

```
from pynput import keyboard
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal

import imageprocess
class key_monitor(QObject):
    image_processed_km = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prev_key = None
        self.listener = None
        self.imageprocessing_obj = imageprocess.image_process()
        self.imageprocessing_obj.image_processed.connect(self.image_processed_km.emit)


    def on_press(self,key):
        pass

    def on_release(self,key):
        if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:

            if key.char.lower() == "j":
                self.prev_key = key.char.lower()
            elif key.char.lower() == "k" and self.prev_key == "j":
                print("key combination j+k pressed")
                self.prev_key = None
                self.imageprocessing_obj.process_image()
        else:
            self.prev_key = None

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.stop()

    def monitor_for_hotkey_combo(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release = self.on_release) as self.listener:self.listener.join()
```

**imageprocess.py**

```
import uuid,os,sqlite3,pytesseract
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal

class image_process(QObject):
    image_processed = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.screenshot = None
        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect("testdababase.db", check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb (OCRstring text, filepath text)")

    def process_image(self):
        self.screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
        self.screenshot_path =  os.getcwd() + "\\" + uuid.uuid4().hex + ".jpg"
        self.screenshot.save(self.screenshot_path )
        self.ocr_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(self.screenshot)
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testdb (OCRstring, filepath) VALUES (?,?)",(self.ocr_string, self.screenshot_path))
        self.image_processed.emit(self.screenshot_path)
```

Comment: you say *same Sqlite3 database in multiple threads*, but I only see one thread, where are the others?

Comment: @eyllanescthe pynput documentation mentions that listner inherits from threading.thread Source: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/ All callbacks mentioned in the instantiation of listener are called from a `threading.Thread ` as mentioned in the documentation. So therefore I have a Qthread which you see in the main qtgui.py module and the `threading.thread` which you see in the hotkeymonitor.py module

Comment: okay, I understand, but then why is he creating another thread to pyinput his already running on a thread and not blocking the GUI?

Comment: @eyllanesc That's where my problem lies. Since the pynput listener uses `threading.Thread` by default, I'm looking for a way to automatically use the Qthread I've already created for the listener to avoid the milti-threaded access of the SQlite database.

Comment: In a GUI the objective of using threads is not to block the main thread called GUI thread, in your case I see 2 blocking tasks, the first one is pyinput, but it is already executed in a thread so there are no problems with this, and the other is the OCR that must be executed in another thread, the DB access is not blocking, does not consume any resources so it could be executed within the GUI.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah, this works great!. I like how you avoided the multithreaded access of the database by bringing the database interactions into the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a `QThread` is not a *Qt thread*, that is, it is not a new type of thread, `QThread` is a class that manages the native threads of each platform. so the thread that handles `QThread` has the same characteristics of `threading.Thread`.

On the other hand the goal of using threads in a GUI is not to block the main thread called GUI thread, in your `pynput` it already has its thread so there would be no problems. The other task that is blocking is that of the OCR, so we must execute it in a new thread. The task of the database is not expensive, so it is not necessary to create a thread.

**keymonitor.py**

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
from PySide2 import QtCore

class KeyMonitor(QtCore.QObject):
    letterPressed = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release = self.on_release)

    def on_release(self,key):
        if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
            self.letterPressed.emit(key.char.lower())

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.stop()

    def start_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.start()
```

**imageprocess.py**

```
import uuid
import pytesseract

from PIL import ImageGrab

from PySide2 import QtCore

class ProcessWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    processSignal = QtCore.Signal(str, str)

    def doProcess(self):
        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
        screenshot_path =  QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(uuid.uuid4().hex+".jpg")
        screenshot.save(screenshot_path )
        print("start ocr")
        ocr_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot)
        print(ocr_string, screenshot_path)
        self.processSignal.emit(ocr_string, screenshot_path)
        self.thread().quit()
```

**main.py**

```
from keymonitor import KeyMonitor
from imageprocess import ProcessWorker
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import sqlite3

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.last_letter = ""
        self.current_letter = ""

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        lay.addWidget(button)

        self.keymonitor = KeyMonitor()
        self.keymonitor.letterPressed.connect(self.onLetterPressed)

        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect("testdababase.db")
        self.cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb (OCRstring text, filepath text)")
        self.threads = []

    def onClicked(self):
        self.keymonitor.start_monitoring()

    def onLetterPressed(self, letter):
        if self.last_letter:
            if self.current_letter:
                self.last_letter = self.current_letter
            self.current_letter = letter
        else:
            self.last_letter = letter

        if self.last_letter == "j" and self.current_letter == "k":
            print("j+k")
            self.start_processing()

    def start_processing(self):
        thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = ProcessWorker()
        self.worker.processSignal.connect(self.onProcessSignal)
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.started.connect(self.worker.doProcess)
        thread.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        thread.finished.connect(lambda th=thread: self.threads.remove(th))
        thread.start()
        self.threads.append(thread)

    def onProcessSignal(self, ocr, path):
        print(ocr, path)
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testdb (OCRstring, filepath) VALUES (?,?)",(ocr, path))
        self.db_connection.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```